# Access violation with ARB_DEBUG_OUTPUT

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, glload

I am using the `ARB_DEBUG_OUTPUT` extension to catch OpenGL errors but the program crashes after calling my error logging function.

I set up the extension using the code from [this blog post](http://www.altdevblogaday.com/2011/06/23/improving-opengl-error-messages/). Here's the exact code I use to setup the callback:

```
glDebugMessageCallback((GLDEBUGPROC)debugCallbackARB, stderr);
glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS_ARB);
```

Here's `debugCallbackARB`

```
void debugCallbackARB(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity,
                     GLsizei length, const GLchar *message, GLvoid *userParam)
{
    (void)length;
    FILE *outFile = (FILE*)userParam;
    char finalMessage[256];
    formatDebugOutputARB(finalMessage, 256, source, type, id, severity, message);
    logger->debug("%s", finalMessage);
}
```

I use `glEnable` with an invalid parameter to trigger the callback:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH);
```

After printing the error message successfully the program triggers an unhandled exception `Access violation executing location 0x00000500.`

I am using SDL2 to create the OpenGL 3.3 core profile debug context and [GL Load](http://glsdk.sourceforge.net/docs/html/group__module__glload.html) to fetch the GL extension pointers.

The program doesn't crash on the invalid `glEnable` call if I disable the extension.

How can I fix this?

Computer specs:

- NVIDIA GeForce GT 630
- ForceWare 327.23
- Windows 7 x64

**Edit:** I also tried calling the debug callback manually but it doesn't trigger the exception.

Comment: It isn't surprising a call to the callback works - after all, you're the one defining the function. You shouldn't add the `ARB` suffix, however. Also, there is no need to C-cast a ptr to the callback to `GLDEBUGPROC` when invoking `DebugMessageCallback` - the function's signature fits and thus the function ptr already has the right type. Regarding the crash, pls examine the callstack - does the access violation happen in some NVIDIA module? I suppose so, but please confirm.

Comment: What is the point of this statement: `(void)length;`? Since it does nothing, I get the impression you actually meant to do something else there?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: That's the C/C++ to stop the compiler from complaining about unused variables. :D Usually you see that wrapped in a macro, something like `#define UNUSED(x) (void)x;`

Comment: Ah, that is a good point. I had not noticed that the length of the formatted string is unrelated to the length of the input debug message. It (hopefully) truncates the message when it has a length > 255.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the function signature. Turns out it did have a wrong calling convention (cdecl instead of stdcall).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OpenGL callback functions use the `__stdcall` calling convention instead of `__cdecl` that's turned on by default in MSVC2012.

I changed the callback definition to

```
void CALLBACK debugCallbackARB(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity,
                 GLsizei length, const GLchar *message, GLvoid *userParam)
```

using the `CALLBACK` macro defined by the Windows API headers.

The invalid address `0x00000500` is 1280 in decimal and it happens to be a screen width parameter passed in to an initialization function one step higher in the call hierarchy. Because of the invalid calling convention this value was read from the stack instead of the actual return address set by the graphics driver calling the function.